# Scanning an NFC tag using Chrome's NDEFReader browser API on Android always triggers Android's native NFC service, instead of remaining in the webpage

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, browser, nfc

I am currently trying to read and write on a writeable NFC tag using Chrome's `NDEFReader`.
I have gone through [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NDEFReader) and [Google's guide on how to use the API](https://developer.chrome.com/articles/nfc/) and I have followed all the steps mentioned.

The problem I am facing is the following: I have a simple webpage where I create an instance of `NDEFReader` and I use it exactly as described in Google Developer's guide I have linked above. I am serving that webpage through https using ngrok. I open up that webpage on my Android phone, give permission to Chrome to interact with the NFC tag, scan the NFC tag and instead of getting the records information output within my webpage, I get redirected to Android's native NFC service app that lists the records. I have the exact same problem when I'm trying to write on the tag.

Is there a way I can push Chrome to the foreground when I allow it to interact with the NFC tag, so that Android's native NFC service does not kick in?

- Android version: 10 QKQ1.190825.002
- Chrome version on my smartphone: 113.0.5672.131

This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <button id="scanButton" style="padding: 20px; font-size:20px; display: none;">SCAN</button>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="text">
      <button id="write" style="padding: 20px; font-size:20px;">WRITE</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const ndef = new NDEFReader();
    const outputDiv = document.querySelector('#output');
    const writeBtn = document.querySelector('#write');

    const nfcPermissionStatus = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'nfc' });
    if (nfcPermissionStatus.state === 'granted') {
      await read();
    } else {
      document.querySelector('#scanButton').style.display = 'block';
      document.querySelector('#scanButton').onclick = async() => {
        await read();
      };
    }

    async function read() {
      await ndef.scan();

      ndef.onreadingerror = () => {
        outputDiv.textContent = 'Cannot read data from the NFC tag. Try another one?';
      };

      ndef.onreading = ({ message }) => {
        for (const record of message.records) {
          switch (record.recordType) {
            case 'text':
              const textDecoder = new TextDecoder(record.encoding);
              outputDiv.innerHTML += `Text: ${textDecoder.decode(record.data)}<br>`;
              break;
            // currently, I am only interested in parsing text records
            // the rest of the cases are omitted
          }
        }
      };
    } 

    writeBtn.onclick = async() => {
      await ndef.scan();

      try {
        const textInput = document.querySelector('#text');
        await ndef.write({
          records: [{ recordType: 'text', data: textInput.value }]
        }, { ignoreRead: true });

        outputDiv.textContent = `Wrote text: ${textInput.value}`;
      } catch(err) {
        outputDiv.textContent = `Error: ${err}`;
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```